# Which Add-on should I use to file storage my Rails app

Tags: heroku

I have a Rails App launched in Heroku but because of the [Active Storage on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku) I now need a cloud file storage. I know that there is Amazon's S3 but I really don't want to create another account on another service. There isn't another add-on from Heroku that give the storage I need without going 'outside'?

Hope you can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There isn't another add-on from Heroku that give the storage I need without going 'outside'?

While that was the case at one point, that hasn't been true for some time. There are a number of addons available in the marketplace, under the [Data Stores](https://elements.heroku.com/addons) sub-heading, that fit the bill. They are external services but you can access them directly through your Heroku account. A couple examples:

- [HDrive](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/hdrive) - S3 and Azure object storage
- [Cloudcube](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/cloudcube) - S3 addon
- [Bucketeer](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/bucketeer) - S3 addon

These should allow you to leverage external file storage without creating additional account.

Comment: Ah ok! I'll search more about them :D thank you so much